# Translation of "Under Pressure" -- Queen song title

Tags: traducción, modismos

Today I heard *Under Pressure* by Queen on the radio. After the song, the DJ announced the song as *Alta Presión*.  That sounds more to me like "High Pressure" than "Under Pressure."  I would have translated "Under Pressure" as something more like *Bajo Presión*.

Are my translation skills really that bad?  Or is *Alta Presión* an idiomatic expression that translates more closely to *Under Pressure*?

Comment: Related trivia: _Presionando_ is the name of Fobia's cover of _Under Pressure_ on the album [Tributo a Queen - Los Grandes del Rock en Español](http://www.amazon.com/Queen-En-Espanol-Latin-Tribute/dp/B000000OK4/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1323440403&sr=8-1).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No no, your translation skills are really good!! But there is a nuance here that I presume is difficult to get.

The literal translation of **Under Pressure** is

> Bajo Presión

Now, in spanish **Bajo Presión** inherently means that there is high pressure being applied, or else you wouldn't be **Under Pressure**.

So the DJ figured to translate it as **Alta Presión** since that is the real source of being **Under Pressure**.

That is my reasoning.

Edit:

As per comments:

> If you were speaking of people, or a situation being "under pressure," how would you describe that in Spanish?

Well in that kind of situation the most natural to say would be **Bajo presión** or, this will probably sound counter-intuitive but you can also say **con mucha presión** with this one it is obvious that you are under pressure. For instance if you say *Estoy con mucha presión en mi trabajo* it is obvious you are under pressure. (Of course depends on context it can also mean blood pressure). But you wouldn't say alta presión, if you do I would relate it more to blood pressure, (e.g. when you say "Estoy con alta presión").

Comment: If you were speaking of people, or a situation being "under pressure," how would you describe that in Spanish?

Comment: @Flimzy: Made an edit to complete the answer.

Comment: Thanks... I think you've convinced me that I'm not insane, and that the DJ probably just did a poor translation.

Answer (score 2):

`Bajo presión`, definitely. You could also say `presionado`.